# What's wrong with my best_fit memory allocation program?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have this best_fit memory allocation program and I don't know why it works fine for the first allocation and not fine for the second allocation while I have space in my free list (list of free nodes).

```
//find best fit
117 list_t* find_bestfit(list_t* best_node, int sizeToAlloc){
118 
119 
120         best_node=NULL;
121         list_t * temp;
122         temp=freep;
123         while(temp!=NULL){
124 
125                 if (((temp->size) >= sizeToAlloc) && ((best_node == NULL) || ((temp->size) < (best_node->size)))){
126                         best_node = temp;
127                         printf("I am here line 127\n");
128                         printf("best node address is : %llx\n", (long long unsigned) best_node);
129                 }
130                 if( (best_node->size) == sizeToAlloc){
131                         printf("I am here line 130\n");
132                         break;
133                 }
134                 temp = temp->next;
135         }
136         if(best_node == NULL){
137                 printf("I am here line 137 \n");
138                 m_error = E_NO_SPACE;
139                 printf("NOT enough space\n");
140 
141                 //      printf("No space available");
142                 exit(-1);
143         }
144         return  best_node;
145 }
```

And here is how I allocate memory (cosidering I have chuncks of free space):

```
 ptr[0] = Mem_Alloc(360, BESTFIT);
 64    assert(ptr[0] != NULL);
 65    if (ptr[0] != NULL)
 66    {
 67               printf("pointer[0] worked  line 65\n");
 68               printf("360 is allocated at %p \n",ptr[0]);
 69    }
 70 
 71 
 72    printf("reached here \n");
 73    printf("pointer [2] before is %p \n",ptr[2]);
 74    ptr[2] = Mem_Alloc(360, BESTFIT);
 75    printf("pointer [2] after is %p \n",ptr[2]);
 76    assert(ptr[2] != NULL);
 77    if (ptr[2] != NULL)
 78    {
 79                 printf("pointer[2] worked \n");
 80                 printf("360 is allocated at %p \n",ptr[2]);
 81    }
```

Here's the output of the program:

```
I am here line 127
best node address is : 7f4932687000
header address is : 7f4932687000
pointer[0] worked  line 65
360 is allocated at 0x7f4932687008 
reached here 
pointer [2] before is (nil) 
 1360 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) myprogram
```

According to the requests in the comments here is the code for Mem_Alloc:

```
void *Mem_Alloc(int size, int style){


    if( size <= 0 ){
        m_error = E_BAD_ARGS;
        printf("Bad size args\n");
        return NULL;
    }



    //check if size if valid/upper limit stuff

    if(size % ALIGN_EIGHT != 0) {
        size += ( ALIGN_EIGHT - (size % ALIGN_EIGHT) );
    }

    //local variables
    list_t * newfreesp;
    list_t *temp = NULL;    //will return this as a ptr to the allocated spac

    int adjusted_size;
    adjusted_size = size + sizeof(header_t);

    header_t *headptr; //declare pointer for the header space


        printf("come to fill head \n");
    //allocate new header
    header_t fillhead;
    fillhead.size = adjusted_size;
    fillhead.magic = 123;

    switch (style){

        case BESTFIT:
            temp = find_bestfit(temp,adjusted_size);
            break;

        case WORSTFIT:
            temp = find_worstfit(temp,adjusted_size);
            break;
        case FIRSTFIT:
            temp = find_firstfit(temp,adjusted_size);
            break;
        default:
            m_error = E_BAD_ARGS; 
            printf("bad style args\n");
            return NULL;           
            break;


    }

    if(temp != NULL){


        ////////////////only one node in free list////////////////////////
        if(temp == freep && (freep->next == NULL)){


            //all of memory requested
            if(temp->size == adjusted_size){
                freep = tail = NULL;
            }
            //only portion requested
            else{
                freep = (list_t*)((char*)temp + adjusted_size);
                tail = freep;
                //decrements freep size by (size requested + header size)
                freep->size = temp->size - adjusted_size-sizeof(list_t);

            }

        }
        ////////////////more than one node in free list///////////////////////
        else{

            //size requested is the same size as free node-
            //in an a free list with more than 1
            if(temp->size == adjusted_size){

                //temp is first node in free list
                if(temp == freep && (freep->next != NULL)){
                    freep = temp->next;

                }
                //temp some middle node in the list
                else if(temp != tail){          
                    (temp->prev)->next = temp->next;
                    (temp->next)->prev = temp->prev;

                }
                //temp is the tail          
                else{
                    (temp->prev)->next = NULL;
                    tail = temp->prev;

                }


                //sizeToAlloc is only apart of the node in a list with 
                //more than one node
            }else{


                newfreesp =(list_t*) ((char*)temp + adjusted_size);
                newfreesp->size = temp->size - adjusted_size- sizeof(list_t);

                //temp is first node in free list w/ more than one node
                if(temp == freep && (freep->next != NULL) ){
                    newfreesp->next = temp->next;
                    freep = newfreesp;
                }

                //temp some middle node in the list w/ more than one
                else if(temp != tail){  
                    newfreesp->prev = temp->prev;
                    newfreesp->next = temp->next;   
                    (temp->prev)->next=newfreesp;

                }
                //temp is the tail          
                else{
                    //local variables       
                    newfreesp->prev = temp->prev;
                    newfreesp->next = NULL; 
                    (temp->prev)->next=newfreesp;
                    tail = newfreesp;
                }

            }
        }//endelse for (more than more node in list)





        //move temp ptr past the header (8bytes)
        //so it points to the beginning of the allocated
        //space
        temp = (list_t*)((char*)temp + sizeof(header_t));

        //initialise header pointer address
        headptr = (header_t*)((char*)temp - sizeof(header_t));

        printf("header address is : %llx\n", (long long unsigned) headptr);
        //headerpointer: fill this space with the header        
        *headptr = fillhead;



        //cast to void and return pointer to allocated space    
        return (void *) temp;


    }

    else{
        printf("I am here in line 359\n");
        m_error = E_NO_SPACE;
        printf("NOT enough space\n");
        return NULL;
    }


    // carve out 100 bytes
    // change your freep list: sizeOfRegion - 100(approx)
    // return ptr to 100 bytes
    //return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the code for `Mem_Alloc()`.

Comment: You haven't shown the code for `Mem_Alloc`.  Since that is the last function you call before your program crashes, I thought you would consider it important.  Also, how is `ptr` defined?

Comment: I added the code for Mem_Alloc. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: I suggest you output the size of `freep->size` after you adjust it (also for `newfreesp`).  It looks like you are reducing the size by more than your `find_best_fit` function knew about.  That might not be the issue though.  On the surface, it looks like you could have memory corruption from your first call, because when you call `Mem_Alloc` a second time, it never prints the "come to fill head" trace - instead it just crashes.  This indicates there may be an issue with how you are managing those lists.  Look over your code carefully, and add more debug.  Look for NULLs and ridiculous values.